# Getting number of photos from photobucket

Tags: php, photobucket

I am wondering if it is possible to print all images from a photobucket gallery on my website, any ideas or headups where I should start or a piece of sample code I could use to get started would be great.

Basically my idea is to get the number of pictures and the url of the images

so it would create a PHP code that would look like this

```
$max_images = $calculated_images_from_photobucket;
for($print_images = 1; $print_images <= $max_images; $print_images++){
echo '<img src="photobucket.com/gallery/'.$calculated_imagename_from_photobucket.'">'; 
}
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: What is $calculated_imagename_from_photobucke ?

Comment: https://bitbucket.org/photobucket/api-php5-pear/src

Comment: It is supposed to be an image URL that should automaticly be generated from a photobucket gallery, how to get the URL is the question haha, same as how to get $max_images, its just an example to demonstrate that its the 2 functions I would need to make it possible

Comment: refer [here](https://github.com/Rohan-Ravindra-Khude/photobucket)

Comment: refer [here](https://github.com/Rohan-Ravindra-Khude/photobucket) which gets the URL of images from `user library` and `/images/\S`. If you are looking images from different photobucket source, then what is link for it. Please provide the link you are looking for.

Comment: Works perfectly mate, too bad it just takes forever to load.